# How to make child items of ListView take all space inside a Container with fixed height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am having trouble making all my items inside a ListView.separated fit all the space available inside a Container, each with the same height.

```
class DailyWeatherListCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DailyWeatherListCardWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 300,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(112, 176, 250, 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => const Divider()),
            itemCount: 7,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return DailyWeatherCardWidget();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class DailyWeatherCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DailyWeatherCardWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Row(
        children: const [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
              child: Text("Day"),
            ),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.water_drop,
            size: 18,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            child: Text("50%"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.sunny,
              size: 18,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.cloud,
              size: 18,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            child: Text("29° 20°"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code. I want the items generated in ListView.separated to be of the same size and equally displayed inside the Container, occupying all its size, but I dunno what I can do. I tried a lot of differente methods, like wrapping ListView.separated in a Expanded widget, in a Flexible Widget. Does anyone know how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

add scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, In your list view

Comment: didn't work, but I resolved the issue. As I knew how many items will be (it will always be seven), I can just make a column with children. No need to use ListView as it won't be scrollable and won't grow.